# How many LED strips should I buy to cover every inch of my circular shelf?

Tags: geometry

I have a 12" diameter circular shelf that I would like to completely cover with flexible LED strips. The strip type that I am looking at is 0.5" wide and 16.4 feet long. I'm planning on spiraling the wire(s) from the outer edge inward to the center and then cutting off the excess. How many strips should I buy?

Thank you!
Michael

added: Yes, I only want to cover the top side of the shelf - it's between table legs and the lights will shine onto the underside of a frosted glass tabletop, making the table appear to be glowing. And yes, the strips can be cut at any point.

Comment: Is the area you want to cover one side of the circle only?

Comment: And can the strips be cut anywhere you want?

Comment: A quick calculation suggests you need a little more than one: $\pi\cdot 6^2 / (0.5 \cdot 16.4 \cdot 12) \approx 1.15$ strips. But the hard part is probably arranging the strip so that doesn't look awful and still allows it to be lit up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you can think of the shelf as 12 concentric circles, each a half an inch wide.  This will be very similar to the spiral you are after.  So you want $$\sum_{x=1}^{12}\pi x=78\pi\text{ inches}$$

So, 2 strips will suffice.  (this estimate over shoots slightly by measuring the outer edge of each circle)

Comment: Lovely! Thank you oh wizard of the mathematical arts! I vow to use this knowledge only for good! Awaaay!